# How does scp manages to handle Ctrl+C in sink mode

Tags: ssh, scp

I'm curious about how does `scp` handles a situation when a binary file  contains escape sequences - and, in particular, the `Ctrl+C` ("\0x03") character from the programmer's side of view.

I have already tried starting it in sink mode and sending it a "\0x03" character, but it clearly exited upon receiving it:

```
$ perl -e 'print "\x03"'|xsel
$ scp -t /tmp/somefile.txt
^C
$
```

However, transfering of a binary file that contains the same character doesn't fails, though I believe that it should.

I have also tried to read the scp.c:source function's source code to see if it attempts to perform any characters escape, but to my surprise it doesn't appears so.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that the source `scp` instance communicates with the sink instance through a clean data pipe. Any byte values can be sent through the pipe, and no bytes receive any special treatment. This is the expected behavior for an ssh "shell" or "exec" channel with no PTY.

For the longer answer, I'm going to restrict this to OpenSSH `scp` running on unix systems. I assume that's the scenario that you're talking about.

The special behavior of keystrokes like Ctrl-C (interrupt the process) or Ctrl-D (end of file) is provided by the TTY interface. Programs like the ssh server use a unix feature called PTYs (pseudo-ttys) to provide a TTY interface for network clients. When you run a command like `scp -t ...` within an interactive session, you're running it in the context of a TTY (or PTY), and it's the TTY which would convert a typed Ctrl-C into an interrupt signal. Processes can disable this behavior, but the scp program doesn't do that, because it doesn't need to.

When you run scp in the normal way, like `scp /some/local/file user@host:/some/remote/dir`, the scp process that you launch runs a copy of `ssh` to make the connection to the remote system. The actual command that it runs will be something like this (simplified):

```
ssh user@localhost "scp -t /some/remote/dir"
```

In other words, it starts a copy of ssh which connects to the remote system and runs another copy of `scp`.

When ssh is run in this fashion, specifying a command to run on the remote system, it doesn't request a PTY for the channel by default. So the two `scp` instances will communicate with each other through a clean data pipe with no PTY involved.

Comment: Could you point me a way how could I test running a remote command with SSH in a fashion that it doesn't reacts to Ctrl+C in input? I have no luck with example you specified.

Comment: If you run `ssh user@localhost "scp -t /some/remote/dir"` and then press Ctrl-C, the Ctrl-C will be processed by your local tty and interrupt the ssh process. The remote scp instance will exit because it sees an EOF condition on its input when the ssh session terminates. The remote scp instance doesn't receive the Ctrl-C character or any signal.